# How to access a second styled component from a first, using material ui styled components

Tags: css, material-ui

What is the format for accessing a second styled component using styled from '@mui/system'? I wish to apply a hover to a parent, to give the child some max-height.

Please note this is mui's styled component, not the standard styled-components version.

```
<Container>
  <Inner />
</Container>
```

and

```
const Container = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'inline-block',
    width: '270px',
    height: '270px',
    cursor: 'pointer',

    //here I need to do something like 
      '&:hover Inner {
        maxHeight: '270px',
      }
    //but I don't know the way to write this
}))

const Inner = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '0px',
    left: '0px',
    width: '100%',
    height: '220px',
    maxHeight: '0px',
    backgroundColor: `${theme.palette.secondary.main}`,
    transition: 'max-height 0.3s ease-out',
    overflow: 'hidden',
}))
```

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else has this, the answer is to give your component a className and use that:

```
<Inner className="inner" />

...
'&:hover': {
  '& .inner': {
    maxHeight: '270px',
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem and want to add some additional information:

1. Make sure the capitalization is the same in your component code and your styled-components code. (`className="Inner"` and `'&:hover .Inner'`)
2. I was using Typescript and could only get the syntax to work when I wrote it like this:

   ```
   '&:hover .Inner': {
        maxHeight: '270px',
    },
   ```